# Android M permissions never wants to show option with a checkbox "Never ask again"

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

[image]when we proceed with android M permissions on the first attempt the option checkbox "Never ask again" do not appears , here if we do "Deny" and than again opens the dialog we see an option checkbox "Never ask again". I never wants to show it from the second attempt how to achieve this?

Here i wants to make a note that i never want to show the checkbox "Never ask again". how to hide from the second attempt on doing

```
FragmentCompat.requestPermissions(fragment, permissions, requestCode);
```

Comment: @ IntelliJ Amiya my question is different probably as i never wants to show the  checkbox “Never ask again”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never wants to show it from the second attempt how to achieve this?

-> You can't and you shouldn't. The only way is to re-implement all the dialogs yourself, which is as crazy as it sounds.

Comment: Alessio thanks for the reply, thanks you for the answer. Is it possible to create such dialog implementation without investing too much time? the answer will be accepted very soon

Comment: @JiteshUpadhyay it will be very helpful to me if you would give me the context, of why you're trying to do so. I strongly discourage to 'fight against the system', and also I would discourage you to remove from the user the possibility to 'never ask again'. Android's permissions make quite a lot of sense, and theirs APIs allow you to have all the information you need to have to handle all cases, because you can always ask the system if the user has granted you *that* permission or not, revoked it, and also if she revoked it selecting the naa option. Possible it possible, but it makes no sense.

Comment: One more comment: it's possible I think, but it will be unnecessary over-complicated, I mean, seriously over-complicated ... and you would have to package some modified classes in your own apk, and keep compatibility for them, so you should really need a strong valid good reason for going through all the trouble.

Comment: Alessio  many thanks for the reply and comment, agreed upon the valuable comments given by you.